# My jQuery script is not working on my Node.js Express app

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a project with Node.js, Express and MongoDB. I'm having trouble posting my data (comprising of a date and YouTube link) to the database in the format I want it to go in. The database view has a form that allows the user to enter in a date and corresponding link that'll queried below the submission form in a list of entries and in another view which'll grab the link to the YouTube videos. I'm using Twitter Bootstrap to create the views. When I use `type="date"` the date format used by my browser doesn't correspond with the date format I am using in my MongoDB database. So as a work around I am using jQuery UI to change the date format. But when I try to load the script (I've connected to the static files using app.use `('public/js', express.static(path.join(__dirname + 'public/js')));` and my script.js file is in the public/js folder but doesn't seem to be running.

This is my app.js code:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var database = require('./routes/database');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('public/js', express.static(path.join(__dirname + 'public/js')));
app.use('public/css', express.static(path.join(__dirname + 'public/css')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/database', database)
app.use('/create', database)

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;

app.listen(8080);

console.log("The server has started");
```

And here is my script.js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Date picker jQuery
    $(function() {
        $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
        $( "#format" ).change(function() {
          $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", $( this ).val() );
        });
      });
    console.log("This worked!!");
});
```

And here is the code for the view:

```
extends layout

block content
    .container
      .row
        .col-s-12
          h1 The Mandela Diaries Database
      .row
        .col-s-4
          h3 Add Entry
      .row
        .col-s-12
          form.form-inline(method='post', action='/create')
            .form-group
              label(for='date') Date: 
              input#datepicker.form-control.datepicker(type='text', value='date')
            p
              | Format options:
              br
              select#format
                option(value='mm/dd/yy') Default - mm/dd/yy
                option(value='yy-mm-dd') ISO 8601 - yy-mm-dd
                option(value='d M, y') Short - d M, y
                option(value='d MM, y') Medium - d MM, y
                option(value='DD, d MM, yy') Full - DD, d MM, yy
                option(value="'day' d 'of' MM 'in the year' yy") With text - 'day' d 'of' MM 'in the year' yy
            .form-group
              label(for='link') Link: 
              input#link.form-control(type='string', value='link')
            button.btn.btn-default(type='submit') Submit
      .row
        #entries.col-s-12
          ul

          script(type'text/javascript', scrc='../public/js/script.js')
```

And I am using Jade as a template for the HTML.

Comment: So what is the problem - loading the script (check 404 error) or posting the datetime?

Comment: I'm not getting any 404 errors. The static files seem to be getting accessed by the server but the jQuery isn't working. I even added a alert("This works"); function as a test and it's not working.

Comment: And there is not any JS error? I put you code in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4no9o7sc/ and it prints the message.

Comment: No JS errors. I don't see any being logged.

Comment: put breakpoint inside $.ready handler and check why it doesn't get to the console.log

Comment: Try aligning that `script` tag with your `.container`. Also you have a typo in the script `scrc`.